# Multiple sessions for one servlet in Java

Tags: java, session

I have one servlet taking care of multiple sites and therefore I want to have different sessions for different sites, even if its the same user.

Is there any support for this in Java or do I need to prefix the attribute names instead? I guess prefixing is not a good idea.

/Br Johannes

Comment: Can I do something like setting path manually to help the situation?

Comment: Please define the term 'multiple sites'

Comment: Yeah I agree, my definition was bad :) . 

The same servlet will show different html-pages depending on different url-parameters. For different url-parameters I would like to have different Sessions, even though its the same user.

Answer (score 2):

This CANNOT be done in the servlet container based on URL parameters alone; you'll have to do it yourself. Instead of dealing with attribute prefixes in your servlet, however, the easiest way to manage "separate" sessions is via filter:

1. Write a simple wrapper class for HttpSession. Have it hold a Map of attributes and back all attribute / value methods by said map; delegate all the other methods to the actual session you're wrapping. Override `invalidate()` method to remove your session wrapper instead of killing the entire "real" session.
2. Write a servlet filter; map it to intercept all applicable URLs.
3. Maintain a collection of your session wrappers as an attribute within the real session.
4. In your filter's `doFilter()` method extract the appropriate session wrapper from the collection and inject it into the request you're passing down the chain by wrapping the original request into HttpServletRequestWrapper whose getSession() method is overwritten.
5. Your servlets / JSPs / etc... will enjoy "separate" sessions.

Note that Sessions's "lastAccessedTime" is shared with this approach. If you need to keep those separate you'll have to write your own code for maintaining this setting and for expiring your session wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this problem too, and I went with ChssPly76's suggestion to solve it. I thought I'd post my results here to provide a reference implementation. It hasn't been extensively tested, so kindly let me know if you spot any weaknesses.

I assume that every request to a servlet contains a parameter named **uiid**, which represents a user ID. The requester has to keep track of sending a new ID everytime a link is clicked that opens a new window. In my case this is sufficient, but feel free to use any other (maybe more secure) method here. Furthermore, I work with Tomcat 7 or 8. You might need to extend other classes when working with different servlet containers, but the APIs shouldn't change too much.

In the following, the created sessions are referred to as **subsessions**, the original container managed session is the **parent session**. The implementation consists of the following five classes:

The **SingleSessionManager** keeps track of creation, distribution and cleanup of all subsessions. It does this by acting as a servlet filter which replaces the ServletRequest with a wrapper that returns the appropriate subsession. A scheduler periodically checks for expired subsessions ...and yes, it's a singleton. Sorry, but I still like them.

```
package session;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * A singleton class that manages multiple sessions on top of a regular container managed session.
 * See web.xml for information on how to enable this.
 *
 */
public class SingleSessionManager implements Filter {

    /**
     * The default session timeout in seconds to be used if no explicit timeout is provided.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 900;

    /**
     * The default interval for session validation checks in seconds to be used if no explicit
     * timeout is provided.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_SESSION_INVALIDATION_CHECK = 15;

    private static SingleSessionManager instance;

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    protected int timeout;
    protected long sessionInvalidationCheck;

    private Map<SubSessionKey, HttpSessionWrapper> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<SubSessionKey, HttpSessionWrapper>();

    public SingleSessionManager() {
        sessionInvalidationCheck = DEFAULT_SESSION_INVALIDATION_CHECK;
        timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
    }

    public static SingleSessionManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingleSessionManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
        chain.doFilter(wrapper,  response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig cfg) throws ServletException {
        String timeout = cfg.getInitParameter("sessionTimeout");
        if (timeout != null && !timeout.trim().equals("")) {
            getInstance().timeout = Integer.parseInt(timeout) * 60;
        }

        String sessionInvalidationCheck = cfg.getInitParameter("sessionInvalidationCheck");
        if (sessionInvalidationCheck != null && !sessionInvalidationCheck.trim().equals("")) {
            getInstance().sessionInvalidationCheck = Long.parseLong(sessionInvalidationCheck);
        }

        getInstance().startSessionExpirationScheduler();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new session ID.
     * 
     * @return A new unique session ID.
     */
    public String generateSessionId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    protected void startSessionExpirationScheduler() {
        if (scheduler == null) {
            scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            final Runnable sessionInvalidator = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    SingleSessionManager.getInstance().destroyExpiredSessions();
                }
            };
            final ScheduledFuture<?> sessionInvalidatorHandle =
                    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(sessionInvalidator
                            , this.sessionInvalidationCheck
                            , this.sessionInvalidationCheck
                            , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the timeout after which a session will be invalidated.
     * 
     * @return The timeout of a session in seconds.
     */
    public int getSessionTimeout() {
        return timeout;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a session.
     * 
     * @param uiid
     *            The user id this session is to be associated with.
     * @param create
     *            If <code>true</code> and no session exists for the given user id, a new session is
     *            created and associated with the given user id. If <code>false</code> and no
     *            session exists for the given user id, no new session will be created and this
     *            method will return <code>null</code>.
     * @param originalSession
     *            The original backing session created and managed by the servlet container.
     * @return The session associated with the given user id if this session exists and/or create is
     *         set to <code>true</code>, <code>null</code> otherwise.
     */
    public HttpSession getSession(String uiid, boolean create, HttpSession originalSession) {
        if (uiid != null) {
            SubSessionKey key = new SubSessionKey(originalSession.getId(), uiid);
            if (!sessions.containsKey(key) && create) {
                HttpSessionWrapper sw = new HttpSessionWrapper(uiid, originalSession);
                sessions.put(key, sw);
            }
            HttpSessionWrapper session = sessions.get(key);
            session.setLastAccessedTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            return session;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public HttpSessionWrapper removeSession(SubSessionKey key) {
        return sessions.remove(key);
    }

    /**
     * Destroy a session, freeing all it's resources.
     * 
     * @param session
     *            The session to be destroyed.
     */
    public void destroySession(HttpSessionWrapper session) {
        String uiid = ((HttpSessionWrapper)session).getUiid();
        SubSessionKey key = new SubSessionKey(session.getOriginalSession().getId(), uiid);
        HttpSessionWrapper w = getInstance().removeSession(key);
        if (w != null) {
            System.out.println("Session " + w.getId() + " with uiid " + uiid + " was destroyed.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("uiid " + uiid + " does not have a session.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy all session that are expired at the time of this method call.
     */
    public void destroyExpiredSessions() {
        List<HttpSessionWrapper> markedForDelete = new ArrayList<HttpSessionWrapper>();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        for (HttpSessionWrapper session : sessions.values()) {
            if (time - (session.getLastAccessedTime() / 1000) >= session.getMaxInactiveInterval()) {
                markedForDelete.add(session);
            }
        }
        for (HttpSessionWrapper session : markedForDelete) {
            destroySession(session);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove all subsessions that were created from a given parent session.
     * 
     * @param originalSession
     *            All subsessions created with this session as their parent session will be
     *            invalidated.
     */
    public void clearAllSessions(HttpSession originalSession) {
        Iterator<HttpSessionWrapper> it = sessions.values().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HttpSessionWrapper w = it.next();
            if (w.getOriginalSession().getId().equals(originalSession.getId())) {
                destroySession(w);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setSessionTimeout(int timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

}
```

A subsession is identified by a **SubSessionKey**. These key objects depend on the uiid and the ID of the parent session.

```
package session;

/**
 * Key object for identifying a subsession.
 *
 */
public class SubSessionKey {

    private String sessionId;
    private String uiid;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of {@link SubSessionKey}.
     * 
     * @param sessionId
     *            The session id of the parent session.
     * @param uiid
     *            The users's id this session is associated with.
     */
    public SubSessionKey(String sessionId, String uiid) {
        super();
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.uiid = uiid;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((sessionId == null) ? 0 : sessionId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((uiid == null) ? 0 : uiid.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SubSessionKey other = (SubSessionKey) obj;
        if (sessionId == null) {
            if (other.sessionId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!sessionId.equals(other.sessionId))
            return false;
        if (uiid == null) {
            if (other.uiid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!uiid.equals(other.uiid))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SubSessionKey [sessionId=" + sessionId + ", uiid=" + uiid + "]";
    }

}
```

The **HttpServletRequestWrapper** wraps a HttpServletRequest object. All methods are redirected to the wrapped request except for the `getSession` methods which will return an `HttpSessionWrapper` depending on the user ID in this request's parameters.

```
package session;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Wrapper class that wraps a {@link HttpServletRequest} object. All methods are redirected to the
 * wrapped request except for the <code>getSession</code> which will return an
 * {@link HttpSessionWrapper} depending on the user id in this request's parameters.
 *
 */
public class HttpServletRequestWrapper extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private HttpServletRequest req;

    public HttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest req) {
        super(req);
        this.req = req;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpSession getSession() {
        return getSession(true);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpSession getSession(boolean create) {
        String[] uiid = getParameterMap().get("uiid");
        if (uiid != null && uiid.length >= 1) {
            return SingleSessionManager.getInstance().getSession(uiid[0], create, req.getSession(create));
        }
        return req.getSession(create);
    }
}
```

The **HttpSessionWrapper** represents a subsession.

```
package session;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext;

/**
 * Implementation of a HttpSession. Each instance of this class is created around a container
 * managed parent session with it's lifetime linked to it's parent's.
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HttpSessionWrapper implements HttpSession {

    private Map<String, Object> attributes;
    private Map<String, Object> values;
    private long creationTime;
    private String id;
    private String uiid;
    private boolean isNew;
    private long lastAccessedTime;
    private HttpSession originalSession;

    public HttpSessionWrapper(String uiid, HttpSession originalSession) {
        creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastAccessedTime = creationTime;
        id = SingleSessionManager.getInstance().generateSessionId();
        isNew = true;
        attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Enumeration<String> names = originalSession.getAttributeNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = names.nextElement();
            attributes.put(name, originalSession.getAttribute(name));
        }
        values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (String name : originalSession.getValueNames()) {
            values.put(name, originalSession.getValue(name));
        }
        this.uiid = uiid;
        this.originalSession = originalSession;
    }

    public String getUiid() {
        return uiid;
    }

    public void setNew(boolean b) {
        isNew = b;
    }

    public void setLastAccessedTime(long time) {
        lastAccessedTime = time;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAttribute(String arg0) {
        return attributes.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getAttributeNames() {
        return Collections.enumeration(attributes.keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public long getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastAccessedTime() {
        return lastAccessedTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxInactiveInterval() {
        return SingleSessionManager.getInstance().getSessionTimeout();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return originalSession.getServletContext();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpSessionContext getSessionContext() {
        return new HttpSessionContext() {

            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getIds() {
                return Collections.enumeration(new HashSet<String>());
            }

            @Override
            public HttpSession getSession(String arg0) {
                return null;
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String arg0) {
        return values.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getValueNames() {
        return values.keySet().toArray(new String[values.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        SingleSessionManager.getInstance().destroySession(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

    @Override
    public void putValue(String arg0, Object arg1) {
        values.put(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAttribute(String arg0) {
        attributes.remove(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeValue(String arg0) {
        values.remove(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttribute(String arg0, Object arg1) {
        attributes.put(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxInactiveInterval(int arg0) {
        SingleSessionManager.getInstance().setSessionTimeout(arg0);
    }

    public HttpSession getOriginalSession() {
        return originalSession;
    }

}
```

The **SessionInvalidator** is an `HttpSessionListener` that takes care of cleaning all subsessions in case of the invalidation of their parent session.

```
package session;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

/**
 * Session listener that listens for the destruction of a container managed session and takes care
 * of destroying all it's subsessions.
 * <p>
 * Normally this listener won't have much to do since subsessions usually have a shorter lifetime
 * than their parent session and therefore will timeout long before this method is called. This
 * listener will only be important in case of an explicit invalidation of a parent session.
 * </p>
 *
 */
public class SessionInvalidator implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        SingleSessionManager.getInstance().clearAllSessions(arg0.getSession());
    }

}
```

Enable everything by putting the following in your web.xml

```html
<filter>
  <filter-name>SingleSessionFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>de.supportgis.sgjWeb.session.SingleSessionManager</filter-class>
  <!-- The timeout in minutes after which a subsession will be invalidated. It is recommended to set a session timeout for the servled container using the parameter "session-timeout", which is higher than this value. -->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>sessionTimeout</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <!-- The intervall in seconds in which a check for expired sessions will be performed. -->
    <param-name>sessionInvalidationCheck</param-name>
    <param-value>15</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SingleSessionFilter</filter-name>
  <!-- Insert the name of your servlet here to which the session management should apply, or use url-pattern instead. --> 
  <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
  <listener-class>session.SessionInvalidator</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Timeout of the parent session -->
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>40</session-timeout>
  <!-- Session timeout interval in minutes -->
</session-config>
```

Comment: I've replied with some bug fixes below

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).  It will manage individual sessions for individual servlet applications.

Comment: Yeah Im using Tomcat.

The same servlet will show different html-pages depending on different url-parameters. For different url-parameters I would like to have different Sessions, even though its the same user

Comment: @Johannes : How did you handle that situation. I am in the same position where you were 2 years before.... :'(

Answer (score 0):

The session is unique for a combination of user and web application. You can of course deploy your servlet in several web applications on the same Tomcat instance, but you will not be able to route the HTTP request to different web applications simply based on URL parameters unless you evaluate the URL parameters in a second servlet and redirect the browser to a new URL for the specific web app.

Different servlet containers or J2EE app servers may have different options for routing requests to specific web applications, but AFAIK out of the box, Tomcat can only delegate the request based on either host name or base directory, e.g.:

- http://app1/... or http://server/app1/... is delegated to app1
- http://app2/... or http://server/app2/... is delegated to app2, and so on

Answer (score 0):

here is a bug fix for user3792852's reply

```
public HttpSession getSession(String uiid, boolean create, HttpSession originalSession)
{
    if (uiid != null && originalSession != null)
    {
        SubSessionKey key = new SubSessionKey(originalSession.getId(), uiid);
        synchronized (sessions)
        {
            HttpSessionWrapper session = sessions.get(key);
            if (session == null && create)
            {
                session = new HttpSessionWrapper(uiid, originalSession);
                sessions.put(key, session);
            }
            if (session != null)
            {
                session.setLastAccessedTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
            return session;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```